# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in wp-includes/query.php on line 28

Tags: php, html, wordpress, line

I have my own `Wordpress` site and one day when I tried to add new post I couldn't sign in and it said this

**Fatal error:**

> Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home3/accountName/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 28

PLz help me !

Comment: Try disabling all plugins, and try to log in again. [How to do it](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/)

Comment: i can't even sign in to the dashboard .I see the site as visitor

Comment: Look into the link i've attached to my previous comment. There you'll see how to disable the plugins without admin access